# Custom Post_Type Plugin causes Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in wp-includes/post.php

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

I developed a theme and some plugins for a wordpress site.
The plugins are all for custom post types. I tried searching for several hours for a solution but all the solutions I find do not seem to be working for me. Many solutions suggest that an array needs to be called for the foreach argument to work, but I'm fairly certain that my plugin already uses an array accurately. I created a fully working site on my local dev without any errors, but when I install any of the plugins on a live subdirectory of my website (for a demo), I get the following three errors:

1. "**Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home3/adamshap/public_html/usdbls/wp-includes/post.php on line 1468**"
2. "**Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/adamshap/public_html/usdbls/wp-includes/post.php:1468) in /home3/adamshap/public_html/usdbls/wp-includes/option.php on line 787**"
3. "**Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/adamshap/public_html/usdbls/wp-includes/post.php:1468) in /home3/adamshap/public_html/usdbls/wp-includes/option.php on line 788**"

Additional info:
I only receive the errors when uploading my custom post_type plugins (not the theme I developed, just the plugins).
The errors appear on all of my plugins, not any single one.
I know the error lies with the plugins I made, so I need to find out how to fix my plugins, not the wordpress core files.

The first error points to line 1468 of wp-includes/post.php.
The corresponding section of code is as follows:

```
if ( $args->register_meta_box_cb )
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_' . $post_type, $args->register_meta_box_cb, 10, 1 );

$args->labels = get_post_type_labels( $args );
$args->label = $args->labels->name;

$wp_post_types[ $post_type ] = $args;

add_action( 'future_' . $post_type, '_future_post_hook', 5, 2 );

foreach ( $args->taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( $taxonomy, $post_type );
}
```

The second and third errors point to this section of code on the wp-includes/option.php file:

```
// The cookie is not set in the current browser or the saved value is newer.
$secure = ( 'https' === parse_url( site_url(), PHP_URL_SCHEME ) );
setcookie( 'wp-settings-' . $user_id, $settings, time() + YEAR_IN_SECONDS, SITECOOKIEPATH, null, $secure );
setcookie( 'wp-settings-time-' . $user_id, time(), time() + YEAR_IN_SECONDS, SITECOOKIEPATH, null, $secure );
$_COOKIE['wp-settings-' . $user_id] = $settings;
```

Seeing as both of these files are wordpress core files, I believe the error is actually within my plugin code and not the above snippets. The dropbox link below links to a txt file of one of my completed plugins (it was over the character limit for stackoverflow).

https://www.dropbox.com/s/137djd6x13wp2e5/about-intro.txt?dl=0

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: $args->taxonomies is obviously not an array at that point. as for the headers already sent, they're a side effect of the FIRST error, which triggered sending headers.

Comment: That makes sense. Would you suggest me deleting that portion of the question to focus only on the first error? What things might cause that first error? I'm still assuming that the true source is in the plugin file I created, and not in the wp core files. Is that likely the case?

Comment: no idea, actually. I try to avoid wordpuke's (that's not a typo) guts as much as possible. but somewhere the taxonomies thing isn't what it's supposed to be. I'd suggest doing a `var_dump()` on it and see what it really is.

Comment: Where would I execute the var_dump? Is that just to see what value is being applied to $args in the first snippet?

Comment: pretty much. figure out what's there, then start backtracking and figure out where what should have been in there (an array) didn't go in there.

Comment: I think I made some progress. I edited that line in wp-includes/post.php to read, "if (is_array($taxonomy) || is_object($taxonomy)) { foreach ($args ->taxonomies as $taxonomy) { register_taxonomy_for_object_type($taxonomy, $post_type); } }". I no longer have any errors, but I'm very concerned about leaving the wordpress core file edited. Is there a better way to incorporate this solution, or will this solution cause problems down the line?

Comment: given that's core WP code, you should be looking at whatever's USING that code.e.g. fix in the inputs, rather than fiddling with the processing/output.

Comment: Thanks, Marc. I found the problem (real problem). My register_post_type $args array was defining taxonomies as false instead of an array. Got rid of all my errors and I was able to return the wp-includes/post.php file back to the original.

Answer (score 6):

SOLUTION FOUND, thanks in part to user Marc B for his comments above.

We found that of the three errors, the real error was just the first one, with the additional two errors resulting from the first error.

My first solution was to change the wp-includes/post.php file (lines 1468 - 1470) from:

```
foreach ( $args->taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( $taxonomy, $post_type );
}
```

to this:

```
if (is_array($taxonomy) || is_object($taxonomy)) { 
    foreach ($args ->taxonomies as $taxonomy) {
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type($taxonomy, $post_type);
    } 
}
```

Although this solved my issue, it is a bad solution because it requires editing the wp core files. After Marc B's suggestion of a var_dump and to find the section of my plugin that uses the taxonomy array (incorrectly), I found the real solution:

My plugin registered a custom post_type with the following original code:

```
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Statement', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'About Statement', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array('',''),
        'taxonomies'          => false,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => false,     
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'query_var'           => 'about',
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'about_type', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'about_post_type', 0);
```

As you can see, the $args array was defining 'taxonomies' as 'false'. This is what was causing the error. The solution was to simply change the value 'false' to an array. The fixed function is below:

```
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Statement', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'About Statement', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array('',''),
        'taxonomies'          => array(),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => false,     
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'query_var'           => 'about',
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );
```

While looking for an answer myself, I found that a lot of people seem to have this issue. If you are looking for a similar solution, I would recommend looking at your plugin's register_post_type function to see how the array is handling taxonomies.

Comment: Five years on and still an issue - thanks for this!